# TFVC visual studio mac, not login

Tags: macos, visual-studio, tfvc

Trying to connect to VSTS from visual studio (MAC), I downloaded TFS integration and  connected to VSTS but I cannot see any repository once I login.

When I try to Add host, it comes up with fields to add server, I added all the details correctly but always get message as "Not able to authenticate", please if anyone can guide that will be really appreciate.

Not it is TFVS repository and not git.

Cheers,
A[TFVS login screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvV4E.png)

Comment: What credentials are you authenticating with?  You'll probably need a Personal Access Token if you haven't already created one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes I created personal token accecss Token. But still not working